# how to get 'value' and 'Lable' from this array

Tags: php

how to get 'value' and 'Lable' from this array

```
array(2) {
  ["value"]=>
  string(4) "Easy"
  ["label"]=>
  string(8) "راحت"
}
```

Comment: [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: There is no "Lable" in that array...

Comment: this? `echo $array['value']; echo $array['label'];`

Answer (score 0):

use array_keys() and array_values() for the same.

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
echo $array['value']; 
echo '<br>';
echo $array['label'];
```

output:

Easy

راحت